# Why is the Bounty privilege given at 75 reputation, while minimum bounty is 50 reputation?

Tags: discussion, bounties, privileges

I don't understand why you can't place a bounty until you get 75 rep but the minimum bounty is 50. Wouldn't it make more sense to be able to place a bounty when you have 51 rep since you have enough rep to place a 50 rep bounty and you will still have 1 rep left so you don't go under 1?

Comment: Why the down-votes?

Comment: Because on metas votes tend to reflect whether or not a person agrees with the idea you're expressing rather that whether or not your post was well-constructed. It takes some getting used to. In this case it's presumably somebody who does not feel that it would make more sense to have the threshold lowered. I wouldn't think too hard about it.

Comment: @JasonC That's dumb they should have a different button for that, that doesn't affect your rep

Comment: Ha, well, I wouldn't go there. That's a losing battle.

Comment: Is this a feature request?

Comment: @John is what a feature request?

Comment: @John I'm not saying that I want this to happen because I already have 75 rep (stackoverflow). I'm just wondering why

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, I don't know the official reason why bounty is at 75 and comments are at 50, but some guesses (I suppose I might as well make an answer out of my comments):

It makes sense to me that you'd want to give new users the experience of leaving comments before you give them the experience of setting bounties ([re](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292245/why-is-the-bounty-privilege-given-at-75-reputation-while-minimum-bounty-is-50-r?noredirect=1#comment949264_292247)), especially given that leaving a bounty can cost you the privileges. If you could leave bounties but weren't allowed to comment, you might be encouraged to peg your rep low leaving a bounty to get more attention to a question.

I think it also might be confusing, too: Commenting on stuff is a ubiquitous action anybody who uses the internet is familiar with, but bounties are more of a niche thing. So it makes sense to me that you'd let new users do something they're familiar with before you let them do something that's a specialized feature of SE sites that they may not yet understand.

Also having the privilege in the middle there, unrelated to bounty behavior, is nice because earning privileges feels good and 75 is a good spot to strive for. It adds a little bit of encouragement to the initial rep gain for a new user on a site. If bounties and comments were both at 50/51 and the next was at 100, there'd be a little gap there where you're faced with the seemingly daunting task of *doubling* your rep to get a reward.

I don't really think it's *too* much of an issue as it doesn't take a prohibitive amount of effort to get that extra 25. It'd be different if bounties were at, say, 500 or something.

Answer (score 3):

At 50 reputation one gets the Comment Anywhere privilege, and at 100 there are two: Create Chat Room, and  Edit Community Wiki.

So to add extra "level", they decided to put it in between.

Another motive is that one can't have reputation of 0. If we could start bounties with 50 reputation, it means we'll drop to 0, which is impossible. And awarding the privilege at 51 reputation would mean dropping to 1 reputation, which is too low, losing all privileges in one go.

Comment: I edited my question. Sorry for that

Comment: But why don't they switch comment anywhere with bounty? It just seems better to be at the minimum bounty requirement.

Comment: @NoahCristino 50 for comment is pretty high for many users who struggle for every upvote, raising it will make no sense.

Comment: Well maybe they could change something else or multiple things to make it 50

Comment: Answer edited. @NoahCristino

Comment: Maybe bounties could be 51, comments 50 and either create chatroom or edit community wiki could go down to 75

Comment: Why not let people decide what they want to do as soon as they have enough rep? They could gain tons of rep. High risk high reward. (or low reward) @JasonC

Comment: Good answer but Jason's combined all these comments plus your answer into one